# Default route appears on ethernet interface with DHCP disabled

Tags: ubuntu, routing, ethernet, networkmanager, netplan

I have an Ubuntu system with an ethernet interface (eth0) connected to a router that acts as a DHCP server providing a default route. However I have set eth0 to use a static address and ignore routing since I want to run a script that will test if the router has connectivity and only add a default route via it if so. But whenever I bring the interface up, I see a default route pointing to it:

```
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
```

Curiously this route has no src, metric or proto fields. And more curiously it comes and goes - repeated invocations of `ip route` will sometimes show it present, sometimes not.

The full output of `ip route` is below - currently I have a WiFi interface up and providing a default route which is what I want to use when the ethernet connected router has no connectivity. Deleting the route doesn't help - it just reappears.

Any clues on why this spurious route is appearing?

```
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.67 metric 600
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.0.0/22 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.67
192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.67 metric 600
192.168.96.0/24 dev bond-lan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.96.254
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
```

The netplan config is:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.100.100/24]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: no
        use-routes: no
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: []
    eth2:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond-lan0:
      interfaces: [eth1, eth2]
      addresses: [192.168.96.254/24]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: no
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: no
```

Running `ip mon route` shows this:

```
Deleted 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
Deleted broadcast 192.168.100.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
Deleted local 192.168.100.100 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.100.100
local 192.168.100.100 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.100.100
broadcast 192.168.100.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
Deleted 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
Deleted broadcast 192.168.100.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
Deleted local 192.168.100.100 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.100.100
local 192.168.100.100 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.100.100
broadcast 192.168.100.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
Deleted 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100
```

Repeated ad nauseum.

Comment: Does `ip mon route` show it being added/removed repeatedly? The lack of a 'proto' field being _shown_ usually implies it has the default value, 'proto boot' i.e. added via manual `ip route add`. Are there any unusual processes in `ss -f netlink 'src = rtnl'` or in `extrace` / `forkstat` / `execsnoop`?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes - did not know about `ip mon route`, but have updated the question with the output.

Comment: `extrace` seems to show the culprit is `/sbin/dhclient-script`:
`
  39145 /bin/sh /sbin/dhclient-script
    39146 run-parts --list /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d
    39147 systemctl is-enabled systemd-resolved
    39148 ip -4 addr add 192.168.100.100/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.100.255 valid_lft 5 preferred_lft 5 dev eth0 label eth0
    39149 ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1500
    39151 ip -4 route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
`

Comment: That sounds like a problem – you probably don't want to have dhclient running alongside systemd-networkd...

Comment: Indeed. It seems that dhclient is being run by dhcpd which is supposed to be only acting as a server for the local LAN.

Comment: Or maybe not - if I stop `isc-dhcp-server` the route updates still happen.

Comment: You probably have a permanent dhclient process that's spawning the dhclient-script, so just look at which systemd service it belongs to: `systemctl status <pid>`

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have made the problem go away. First, the background:

I'm using `netplan` with `systemd-networkd`, so configuring by editing `/etc/netplan/50-network.yaml`, running `netplan apply` which updates files under `/run/systemd/network/` which are read by `systemd-network`. As far as I was aware, this all supersedes the files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`, which are not touched by netplan.

However, it seems that `ifup` still reads those files, and runs `dhclient` because it believes the interface is a dhcp client. There were files created in that directory during the Ubuntu install, which flagged `eth0` as dhcp mode.

So I removed the files under `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` and after a system reboot the spurious routes are no longer being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate using:

- `ss -f netlink "src = rtnl"` to list processes that are actively connected to *rtnetlink* which is the primary Linux interface for adding/removing routes (as well as IP addresses and other things).
- [`extrace`](https://github.com/leahneukirchen/extrace), [`forkstat`](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/forkstat), `execsnoop` to watch for processes that correspond to brief commands like "ip route add" being repeatedly run.
- `systemctl status <pid>` to determine which service a (running) process belongs to – e.g. the parent process of the "ip route add".

From your extrace/forkstat results, it seems that you have two network clients running side by side – systemd-networkd (as part of netplan) and dhclient (perhaps as part of ifupdown or NetworkManager) or something.

What likely happens:

1. dhclient acquires a lease and adds a route;
2. systemd-networkd (the backend used by Netplan) deletes all "foreign" routes by default;
3. dhclient renews lease and adds the route;
4. systemd-networkd deletes "foreign" routes;
5. repeat

The absence of `proto ...` is normal – dhclient uses `ip route add` to add the route and does not bother specifying a custom protocol value, so it takes the default ("proto boot"), and default values are not shown in the route list (unless you use `ip -d route` I suppose).

Comment: Thanks for the help - your troubleshooting tips were what I needed.